# unsuitable .jre during deployment in other computer

Tags: java, installation, install4j

If a computer does not have the required *.jre* or lets say there is no *.jre* at all in that system, can a *.jre* bundled with the app via **install4j** be used  to make the app install on the computer that does not even have any *.jre* at all. I mean no *.jre* at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you bundle a JRE in the media wizard, the target computer does not need an installed JRE, neither for the execution of the installer, nor for the execution of the installed launchers.